# App testing on roatation on a real iphone device

Tags: iphone, testing, icons, rotation

I have created my first iphone application (very simple app) and I don't have an iphone to test errors on rotation. I don't want to purchase (expensive) apple iphone just for testing rotation.

My app has 3 view controllers. Here is the detail.

1. First view controller has 1 label, 1 round rectangle button, 1 datepicker. It also shows 1 alert on error. No label text or alert text is too long
2. Second view controller has 1 table view which shows only 5 records.
3. Third view controller has 1 textview.

I didn't customize anything. I mean there is no custom icon,custom alerts, custom taleview or custom textview. It doesn't try to access internet. Nothing is complicated and it is running fine on simulator.

Will there be any problem on rotation? I think rotation can cause problems only if there is something customized. Default label text, default table view settings should work fine on rotation.

Is it OK if I submit my app without testing it on an actual iphone device.

Answer (score 2):

You should always test an app in a device before submiting it. Anyway, in this particular case, you can simulate rotation in the device simulator. I think is in the hardware tab, where you can choose the device's orientation.

Comment: or CMD + Left/Right on the keyboard

Answer (score 1):

Consider an iPod Touch - cheaper than an iPhone.

Personally I think that you plan for others to use the device then you can't NOT test in a device. You can't really test the UI on the Simulator. You can't hold the simulator in one hand and try to use the app with your thumbs.

Answer (score 0):

Use the simulator to check rotation. In the Simulator, go to Hardware, then Rotate Right or Rotate Left. Of course, there's no way of knowing if anything will go wrong on an actual device unless you test on one. I would highly recommend buying either and iPhone or the cheaper iPod touch.

Answer (score 0):

You can test rotation in the simulator.

Answer (score 0):

Start the iOS-Simulator, in the Simulators main menu click on "Hardware" and you should see 2 menu items for rotating the simulator to the left and to the right. Click on one and you'll see if there are any problems with your GUI

**Edit_:** I would always test an App on a device. The simulator is, as the name says, just a simulator. It may behave differently than a device. It's not an emulator...